# Why does the remainder of the video not appear in this FFMPEG complex filter graph?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a filter graph where I am trying to shift the first 18 seconds of a long video up by 60 pixels in each frame (the frame size is 1920x1040) without affecting the rest of the video. The graph definition looks like this:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v] trim=start=0:duration=18 [pretitle];\
                 [0:v] trim=start=18,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [remainder];\
                 color=color=black:size=1920x1040 [blank];\
                 [blank][pretitle] overlay=0:-60 [pretitle_shifted];\
                 [pretitle_shifted][remainder] concat [t];\
                 [t] ass=Subtitles.ass,fade=t=out:st=2608.6:d=2 [output]"
-map [output] -map 0:1
```

This filter graph runs without errors, but after the first 18 seconds, the video is just the subtitles on a black background. I can't figure out why. :-(

Comment: I have tried specifying the video input twice as separate inputs and then referencing `[1:v]` for the `[remainder]` part, but the result in the same. :-/

Comment: you can't use [0:v] twice, you should split it first.

Comment: Not the issue here. You can feed source inputs any number of times. To the OP, limit the duration of blank to 18 seconds

Comment: Oh! Thanks! :-)